# Is it possible to query z3's Python API on whether a timeout occured?

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

I  want to limit the time z3 can spend on some problem, which works by setting a timeout with:

```
from z3 import *
solver = Solver()
solver.set(timeout=60000)
# add constraints to solver
result = solver.check()
```

However, I'd like to check whether a timeout actually occurred. `result` is `unknown` in that case, but that might afaik also occur because the issue is not decidable (I'm using theories which are in general not decidable).

So, is there a way to find out whether a timeout has occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, simply use the `reason_unknown` call:

```
from z3 import *
solver = Solver()
solver.set(timeout=1)
x, y = Ints('x y')
solver.add(x**y == x)
result = solver.check()
print result
print solver.reason_unknown()
```

This prints:

```
unknown
timeout
```